# What is the correct way to return a 403 response in YII when the user enters the wrong password

Tags: yii

Helping a friend update the code on his website for an app. Went through the code and there were tons of errors coming from the function below. I tested it and apparently every time a user put in an improper password it would throw an error that would show up in the Application Performance Console.

What is the correct way to return 403 but not consider it an error for the purposes of the Application Performance Console.

```
public function actionLogin($username, $password) {

    if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
        $this->tokenResponse();
    }

    $identity = new ApiClientIdentity($username, $password);

    if ($identity->authenticate()) {

        if (Yii::app()->user->login($identity)) {
            $this->getModule('api')->onAuthenticate();
            $this->tokenResponse();

        }
    } else {
        throw new ApiBaseException(403, Yii::t('api', 'Incorrect login or password'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a correct way to me. What is the exact problem you have with the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to return the error code and get the code to do other things, then just use

```
        http_response_code(403);
```

it will return a 403 but it will still run the following codes.